# 'PreviewKeyUp' was not found in type 'TextBox'

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'm trying to bind the event for PreviewKeyUp and PreviewKeyDown in a Silverlight 5 application.

I haven't been able to find any references to this not being in Silverlight 5, and I haven't been able to find anyone else with this issue.

Is there something I'm missing as to why TextBox does not seem to have any of the Preview events?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [documentation for PreviewKeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeyup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and verified that it is only available in full `.Net` and not in `Silverlight`. In the msdn docu you can click on the "Other Versions" dropdown and see which frameworks are listed. That's how I check if a WPF feature is available for Silverlight.